# Make a summary report in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on this database that I want it to create a summary sum(Amount) report on the all the tables that will be specified. I tried this but it didn't get what I expected.

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) AS Expenditure
FROM Expenditure
WHERE Amount IS NOT NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT SUM(Amount)
FROM auxiliary
WHERE Category IS NOT NULL AND Amount >0;
```

This only shows

[image: query executed message]

and this is want to achieve:

[image]

How do I make that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 'Expenditure' AS TableName, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM Expenditure
WHERE Amount IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Auxiliary' AS TableName, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM auxiliary
WHERE Category IS NOT NULL AND Amount >0;
```